# do demultiplexers remember

Tags: arduino, multiplexer

I'm working on a high school project were i need to make a score board using 420 LEDs controlled by an Arduino.

I can see that the 74HC4105 demultiplexer will let us turn three pins into 8, but if we select pin 000 will the output stay on?  If not, do we have to keep turning all the LEDs on over and over, and will they be dim?

Even if we turn 3 pins into 8, we would need more pins than we have.  How can we control 420 pins with only 20 (or maybe 56 on the Mega?)

We want some kind of circuit that will remember whether each LED should be on or off.

Comment: A demux won't do what you want. Look up shift registers.

Comment: Use a microcontroller.

Comment: Demux is a combinatorial logic component, which has no memory. But Arduino does.

Answer (score 4):

Decoders don't remember, but addressable latches and shift registers do.  A 74HC259 will work much like a demultiplexer, but outputs which are not selected will retain their current state unless or until they are selected.  A 74HC595 shift register has two sets of eight flip flops; clocking the first set ("shift clock") will cause the first flop to capture the state of the data input while the second captures the former state of the first, the third captures the former state of the second, etc.  The state of the eighth will appear on an output pin where it can be connected to the data input of another chip.  Clocking the second set of latches ("register clock") will cause the contents of the first eight to be copied to the second eight.

Using addressable latches, it's easy to set up a system to allow individual bits to be changed directly without having to reload everything.  Using shift registers, it's possible to control an arbitrary number of outputs using only three pins ("data in", "shift clock" and "register clock") but changing any output will require reloading all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest that you look towards serial shift registers.  There is a huge variety of such devices: I'll mention two part numbers but there is a 16-channel device specifically designed for driving LEDs who's part number I don't recall.

The advantage of using serial shift registers is that you can drive a great many output using very few lines from your controller.

The two parts that I use *very* often are the 74hc595 & TPIC6595.  The 74hc part is a standard CMOS device with standard CMOS outputs.  It's good for several mA per output and I use them to drive LEDs directly (with suitable resistor).  The TPIC6595 is similar but it has open-drain sinking outputs good for more than 100 mA at a maximum of 60 Vdc.  I use them for driving relays.

One of my boards has 4- 74hc595 with all outputs driving T1 red LEDs via 100R resistors.  The LED power supply is a Simple Switcher that provides 4 Vdc, all the logic on the board runs at +5 Vdc.  Another board has a pair of TPIC6595 shift registers driving 16 relays.

Both devices work very well.

One trick that I should mention is that you can have multiple strings of shift registers to increase your bandwidth.  Each string of shift registers shares the clock and latch lines but you have separate data lines driving multiple strings.

This trick is useful when you are bit-banging your SPI data.  It's usually not needed if you are using a SPI hardware block in your microcontroller.